# jquery prevent removing every table row

Tags: jquery, tablerow

Table rows can be added or removed. I've set up a confirm to warn the user if they try to remove their own row (the first row that's loaded from the database); if they are setting it up for someone else, they may need to do that. The second row (class=leaderrow) is empty and that leaderrow is what is cloned when the addRow button is clicked.

How can I prevent (or at least warn) the user from removing every leaderrow in the table? If all the leaderrows are removed, the add button fails.

Here's the jQuery:

```
$("a.self").live('click', function(){
   go=confirm('After saving you will lose the ability to edit this organization. Continue to remove yourself?')
    if(go){
       $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    }
    return false; // prevent link to jump to a page.
});


$("a.remove").live('click', function(){
   $(this).parents('tr').remove();
   return false; // prevent link to jump to a page.
});
```

Here's the table, which is part of a form:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" class="unsorted_table">
  <thead>   
      <tr>
           <th>Name*</th>
           <th>Action</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="entries">
      <tr>
            <td>User's own name</td>
            <td><a href="" name="delete_row[]" class="remove self">remove</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="leaderrow">
            <td><select name="leaderid[]" >
              <option value="3">Sue</option>
              <option value="4">Jeannie</option>
              <option value="5">Kerry</option>
              <option value="6">Travis</option>
               </select>
            </td>
            <td><a href="" name="delete_row[]" class="remove">remove</a></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
       <tr> 
            <td><p><input type="button" id="addRow" value="Add Another" /></p></td>
       </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("a.remove").live('click', function(){
   if($(this).parents('tr').siblings().size() > 1)
       $(this).parents('tr').remove();
   else
       alert('cant remove');
   return false; // prevent link to jump to a page.
});
```

(untested code, but you get the idea)